# How do I check in GSP Grails more than one time in list

Tags: java, grails, gsp

I would like to do a check in a GSP page. I have a list of products. the list contains about 21 products. I use g:each to loop the products in GSP and if/else for the check. see my code below. but if the product.id not eaqual to 3. The page displays/prints the checkBox "dontCallMe" 21 times and I expect to print it one time. why is that? is there other way to do the check? thanks

```
     <g:each in="${products}" var = "product">
                        <g:if test="${product.id == '3'}">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                             <g:checkBox name="callMe" checked="true"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Call me
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:if>
                       <g:else>            
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <g:checkBox name="callMe" checked="false"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Call me
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </g:else>
     <g:if test="${product.id == '4'}">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                             <g:checkBox name="callMeAgain" checked="true"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Call me again
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:if>
                       <g:else>            
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <g:checkBox name="callMeAgain" checked="false"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Call me again
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </g:else>
 <g:if test="${product.id == '5'}">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                             <g:checkBox name="dontCallMeAgain" checked="true"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Dont call me again
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:if>
                       <g:else>            
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <g:checkBox name="dontCallMeAgain" checked="false"
                                                value=""/>&nbsp; Dont call me again
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </g:else>
                   </g:each>
```

Comment: are you sure that `product.id` is a `String` value? if it's a number then use `product.id == 3`

Comment: @Igor yes im sure, it is a String

Comment: ok, so you sure that you have 20 items with `id == '3'` and 1 with `id != '3'`. And expect 20 rows of `Call me` and one `Dont call me`, right?

Comment: @Igor what i have is a list of products with different product ids, so i have to do the check different times. So if product.id equal to 1 else print something, if product.id equal to 2 then ... Else ... ect...

Comment: you could use a hashmap ( or other type of map ) for that using product id as the key and the requested string as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 21 products and the `dontCallMe` appears 21 times it means your condition is always false.
What I would do is open up the code in the `debugger` and verify that the object has the expected value and type that you expect.

If your not using a debugger, add a new `<td>`

```
<td>
`${product.id}`
</td>
```

Also, if you don't have a debugger try something like this (havn't tried it myself):

```
<td>
`${product.id?.getClass()}`
</td>
```

### Simplification with Debug Code

Finally, the code could be simplified as follows (please excuse typos):

```
<g:each in="${products}" var = "product">
    <tr>
         <td>
             <g:checkBox name="${product.id == '3' ? 'CallMe' : 'DontCallMe'}" 
             checked="${product.id == '3' ? 'true' : 'false'}"
             value=""/>${product.id == '3' ? 'CallMe' : 'DontCallMe'}"
         </td>
         <td>
              DEBUG: ${product.id} <br/>
              DEBUG: ${product.id?.getClass()} <br/>
         </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it doest work yet. I will explain my problem with examples. I was not clear enough. please see above

Comment: I debug it. the if check works fine. but the else is printing several times

Comment: What you need is to use if, elseif, else though writing multiple elseif tags is a bit repetitive. see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/elseif.html

Comment: is there other way to do that in GSP without the if else??

Comment: you could create 2-3 maps in your controller and pass them as variables to the view. Eg in java : HashMap <Integer, String> callme= new HashMap<Integer, String>(); calleme.put(2, 'what to display'); So then you would pass such an object to the view and use it like callme,get(product.id) . java code works in grails but obviously there are grails alternatives.